# How can I groupby in React/Redux code (new to frontend)?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-redux

I am having difficulty with this function to run in my React/Redux code. I am fairly new to React (mostly work on backend) so I am not sure why it's not running as expected. Is it in the right place? I am also having trouble finding where console.log is printing in the console, since the console is set up with prev action, action, next state patterns....

I have this function defined in my 'actions.js' (where it is also called later on):

```
const groupBy = (array, key) => {
    return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {(
     result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(
        currentValue
      );
      return result;
    }, {}); 
  };
```

Here is where the function is called (same file):

```
export function getAlerts() {
    return dispatch => {
        api.get('notifications', (response) => {
            const grouped = groupBy(response.results.data, 'email');
            dispatch(updateFetchedAlerts(grouped));
        }, (error) => {
            console.warn(error);
        })
    }
}
```

The input, response.results.data,  looks something like this:

```
[{"email": test@email.com, "is_active": true, "alert_id": 1, "pk": 1}, 
{"email": test@email.com, "is_active": true, "alert_id": 2, "pk": 2}, 
{"email": different@email.com, "is_active": true, "alert_id": 1, "pk": 3}]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[{"test@email.com": [{"is_active": true, "alert_id": 1, "pk": 1}, 
                    {"is_active": true, "alert_id": 2, "pk": 2}],
"different@email.com": [{"is_active": true, "alert_id": 1, "pk": 3}]}]
```

but it seems to not be running this function, I've rerun yarn build and used incognito...

UPDATE: This function actually WORKS! Thanks all. The redux developer tools are very helpful. Now the second problem is I need to add in my own keys.... So ideally the result would look like this. Preferably no lodash!:

```
[{"email": "test@email.com",
"alerts": [{"is_active": true, "alert_id": 1, "pk": 1}, 
           {"is_active": true, "alert_id": 2, "pk": 2}]},
{"email": "different@email.com",
"alerts": [{"is_active": true, "alert_id": 1, "pk": 3}]}]
```

Comment: Redux has a lot of boilerplate needed to wire up an application. With the limited snippets you provided, it looks like one of your actions is making an asynchronous api request. You'll at the very least need a package `redux-thunk`  middleware in order to dispatch async actions. Would you be able to port the relevant code into codesandbox for easy debugging?

Comment: I tested your `groupBy` function with your data array, it appears to function as expected, other than the reduce function returns an Object versus an Object *in* an Array (maybe this is typo in question). I did have to quote the email text though. Perhaps the actions `getAlerts` or `updateFetchedAlerts` aren't being called. Do you have the redux-dev-tools installed so you can verify if they are being dispatched or not? Short of this, a running codesandbox would make debugging for us easier.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses. The code is a part of a larger system with middleware, etc set up (which I am still a little iffy on understanding how it all plays together, so I may do some research in that regard). This is my first stackoverflow so I have not used code sandbox but will do and post either tonight or in the morning, Thanks again!

Comment: I installed redux-dev-tools - thanks for the suggestions! It appears the function is actually working as it should. A bug somewhere else then! Thanks again.

Comment: Great! Is there an error/error message or is it just that there's a bug and you're getting unexpected results?

Comment: Well since now this function is working, I also need to add in my own keys... which I am having difficulty doing. Seems all the current suggestion recommend lodash but I would like not to add a dependency...  So really I need:   [{"email": "test"@email.com", "alerts": [......]}, {"email": "different@email.com, "alerts": [.......]}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the same function you used to group by which yields object of shape

```
{ [string]: object[] }
```

Using `Object.entries` allows you to convert this to an array of key-value pairs that you can map to an array of objects with shape

```
{
  email: string,
  alerts: object[],
}
```

Function updates

```
const groupBy = (array, key) =>
  array.reduce((result, { [key]: k, ...rest }) => {
    (result[k] = result[k] || []).push(rest);
    return result;
  }, {});

const groupDataBy = (array, key) =>
  Object.entries(groupBy(array, key)).map(([email, alerts]) => ({
    email,
    alerts
  }));
```

The map function callback `([email, alerts]) => ({ email, alerts })` uses array destructuring to assign the array of `[key, value]` to named variables `email` and `alerts`, and object shorthand notation to create an object with keys named for the variables.

```js
const data = [{
    "email": "test@email.com",
    "is_active": true,
    "alert_id": 1,
    "pk": 1
  },
  {
    "email": "test@email.com",
    "is_active": true,
    "alert_id": 2,
    "pk": 2
  },
  {
    "email": "different@email.com",
    "is_active": true,
    "alert_id": 1,
    "pk": 3
  }
];

const groupBy = (array, key) =>
  array.reduce((result, { [key]: k, ...rest }) => {
    (result[k] = result[k] || []).push(rest);
    return result;
  }, {});

const groupDataBy = (array, key) =>
  Object.entries(groupBy(array, key)).map(([email, alerts]) => ({
    email,
    alerts
  }));

const res = groupDataBy(data, 'email');

console.log(res)
```

Comment: A delayed thank you - I have so much work to do on my JavaScript. Definitely missing python dictionaries right now!

Comment: @anongal No worries. Glad to help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first the console is in the [Browser Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) seccion `console`. There you can view all the console.log. In Chrome you can open it by pressing `F12`.

And the other question, the function that you`re needing is:

```js
//Function groupBy.
function groupBy(array, key) {
  let arrayReduced = array.reduce(
    (result, { [key]: k, ...rest }) => {
      (result[k] = result[k] || []).push(rest);
      return result;
    },
    {}
  );
  return arrayReduced;
}

//Your example data.
const group = [
  {
    email: 'test@email.com',
    is_active: true,
    alert_id: 1,
    pk: 1,
  },
  {
    email: 'test@email.com',
    is_active: true,
    alert_id: 2,
    pk: 2,
  },
  {
    email: 'different@email.com',
    is_active: true,
    alert_id: 1,
    pk: 3,
  },
];

//Function  executed
const result = groupBy(group, 'email');

//Result
console.log(result);
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I edited your answer because your code was mutating original data, log `group` array after your code grouped and you'll see all elements have their `email` property deleted from them. If OP is using redux they will find the state mutated after grouping.